# Use nested reflection to iterate an object that contains objects

Tags: java, reflection

as from the title I need to iterate an object using reflection. What do I have:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public static class ObjectA {
     public ObjectB obj;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public static class ObjectB {
     public String value;
}

String pathValueRetrived = "ObjectA.obj.value";
```

I have to retrieve the value attribute, obviously in a generic way.

Something like:

```
String[] pathValue = StringUtils.split(pathValueRetrived, ".");
ObjectA objectA = //retrive the object with values
Object iterator;
for(String idxPath : pathValue){
  if(iterator != null)
      iterator = iterator.getClass().getDeclaredField(path);
  else
      iterator = objectA.getClass().getDeclaredField(path);
}
```

I thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Also please only tag your question with the java-version you're actually using. **not** providing the exact java-version is also OK, because you're not limiting yourself to a version-specific language feature

Comment: i just edited. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably achieve this with recursion:

```java
public static Object getValue(Object target, String path) throws Exception {
    int index = path.indexOf('.');
    // if we don't find a period (.) or the target is null
    // then just return the target
    if (index < 0 || target == null) {
        return target;
    }
    // get the field name
    String field = path.substring(0, index);
    // get hold of the actual field
    Field field = target.getClass().getDeclaredField(field);
    // used if the field is private
    field.trySetAccessible();
    // recursive call
    return getValue(
        field.get(target),        // gets the value of the field, which is the new target
        path.substring(index + 1) // returns the substring after the found index
    );
}
```

*Some notes*:

1. **No actual error handling**: You may need to implement that yourself, the current solution just throws everything upwards to the caller
2. **No proper input validation**: I.e. if the `path` contains a period at the start or end of the string.
3. **Not tested**

Comment: There's a rather crucial bit missing: getDeclaredField doesn't do what you want here. You need to while-loop over the parentage, because `getDeclaredField` does not get you fields from your superclasses. `getField` does, but that one doesn't get you private/package-private fields. If you want all fields (even (package) private) _and_ from the hierarchy, a while loop is the only answer.